# onclick doesn't work properly with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I tried to use onclick event with Bootstrap radio-buttons to get names and attributes but some how it didn't go well.

Some of the radio-buttons triggered the event but didn't get the name or class ("undefined") and some didn't respond at all.

```
<div class="theContainer">    
  <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option1" onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off" > Radio 1
  <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option2" onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option3" onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  <input type="hidden" class="findme" value="found me!">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option1"       onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off" > Radio 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option2" onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option3" onclick="updateODid()" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
    </label>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/2sc8mc7L/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/2sc8mc7L/6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you have mixed javascript and jquery in a wrong way.

Please check updated snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/2sc8mc7L/12/
The onclick function should be as below :

```
$(".myClass").on('click',function(){
  radioButtonClick($(this));
});

$("label.btn-primary").on('click',function(){
  radioButtonClick($(this).find('.myClass'));
});

function radioButtonClick(_this){
  alert("I'm in!")
  alert (_this.attr('name'));
  alert (_this.attr('class'));
  alert (_this.closest(".theContainer").find(".findme").val());
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but the bootstrap radio button still not working...:(

Comment: Ok please check https://jsfiddle.net/2sc8mc7L/11/ link. I have implemented it as well. As such in bootsrap radio button actual click is on the label so that's why included another jquery code for it as well.

Comment: How it's possible? I'm pressing the radio! why the label?

Comment: The UI is created by bootstrap. The additional HTML is wrapped up by the jquery framework bootstrap jquery framework. And the radio button is hidden in the background. You will able to check it in inspect element after page get load.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/2sc8mc7L/12/ I have made it somewhat dynamic. And let me know wether is has solved your issue or not?

Comment: The real code cotain php varibles and loops and It still doesn't work there.. I'm checking out how to make it fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, Use `updateODid(this)` for `onclick` and it will use current instance

```js
function updateODid(button)
 {
  //alert("I'm in!")
  alert ($(button).attr('name'));
    alert ($(button).attr('class'));
    alert ($(button).closest(".theContainer").find(".findme").val())
 }
```

```html
<div class="theContainer">

    <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option1" onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off" > Radio 1
    
    <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option2" onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
    
    <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option3" onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3


    <input type="hidden" class="findme" value="found me!">


    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      
      <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option1"       onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off" > Radio 1
        
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
      
       <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option2" onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
        
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
      
       <input type="radio" class="myClass" name="options" id="option3" onclick="updateODid(this)" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
        
      </label>
    </div> 

</div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```